# Linear Maps: Prove if $T^2 =0$, then $I-T$ is bijective

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-writing

Let $V$ be a vector space, $T$ is in $L(V)$,
Prove:
If $T^2 = 0$, then $I - T$ is bijective.

the book also gave a hint: in polynomial algebra, $(1-t)(1+t)=(1-t^2)$

I'm not quite sure where to start. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The hint means that $(I-T)(I+T)=I-T^2=I-0=I$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comment indicates:
$$
(I-T)(I+T)=I-T^2=I-0=I
$$
So, we know that $I - T$ has an inverse.

Comment: Is $(I - T)(I + T)$ multiplication or composition?

Comment: @user46944 $I$ and $T$ are matrices... is there a difference?

Comment: I think it would be better to say that if you use the matrix representation of $T$ and $I$ composition becomes the matrix product. But in essence you're composing both functions (otherwise you wouldn't get $T^2 = T\circ T$).

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I haven't studied linear algebra in a while, so I had that question because I'm a little rusty.  It also made me think this subtlety might be lost on the student, too, and so it might be worth mentioning.

Comment: @user46944 this answer is community wiki.  If you have an edit that you feel makes this answer more complete, feel free to make it.  But yes; for linear maps $A,B \in L(V)$, it is traditional to denote the composition $A \circ B$ as $AB$ (whether or not the maps are explicitly given as matrices).

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Oh, ok.  I'll have to look up what community wiki means.  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @user46944 community wiki posts belong "to the community" rather than the poster. In particular, votes on such posts do not count for or against the poster. So, this answer is as much mine to edit as it is yours.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $(I - T)(I + T) = (I + T)(I - T) = I - T^2 = I$ to show injectivity and surjectivity.

Injectivity:

If $(I - T)v = 0$, then $v = (I + T)(I - T)v = 0$, so you have injectivity.

Surjectivity:

If $v \in V$, then $v = (I - T)(I + T)v$, so $v = (I - T)w$ for $w = (I + T)v$. Thus you have surjectivity too.

Answer (score 0):

We see that $I-T:V\to V$. First, we prove that $I-T$ is a injective. Let $u,v\in V$ such that $(I-T)(u)=(I-T)(v)$. This leads to $u-T(u)=v-T(v)$, or $u-v=T(u)-T(v)=T(u-v)$. Since $u-v=T(u-v)$, we deduce $T(u-v)=T[T(u-v)]=T^2(u-v)=0$ by assumption. But $T(u-v)=u-v$, we get $u-v=0$, or $u=v$. We conclude that $I-T$ is injective. Next we prove $I-T$ is an onto from $V$ to $V$. Indeed, for all $v\in V$, we have $v=\left( I-T \right)\left[ v+T\left( v \right) \right]$ (since
$\left( I-T \right)\left[ v+T\left( v \right) \right]=\left( I-T \right)\left( v \right)+\left( I-T \right)\left( T\left( v \right) \right)=v-T\left( v \right)+T\left( v \right)-{{T}^{2}}\left( v \right)=v$)).In other word, for all $v\in V$, we have $v=(I-T)(w)$ where $w=v+T(v)\in V$, and it means that $I-T$ is onto.