# if $T: V \rightarrow V$, $T^{n} = 0$ then $I-T(x)$ is bijective.

Tags: linear-algebra

Trying to show thaT If
 $T: V \rightarrow V$, $T^{n} = 0$ then $I-T(x)$ is bijective.

There is a hint that in polynomials $(1-t)(1+t) = 1 - t^2$.

Not sure where to start.

Comment: Its inverse is $I+T+T^2+\ldots +T^{n-1}$.

Comment: A relevant [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/960111/linear-maps-prove-if-t2-0-then-i-t-is-bijective?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hint handles the $n=2$ case: $(I-T)(I+T)=I-T^2=I$, so $I-T$ is invertible. What is the right generalization of $1+t$ for general $n$?

Comment: For n: it is $(1+T+T^2+...+T^{n-1})$ will be the inverse $I-T$

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**
$$I-T^n=I.$$
Then factor $I-T^n$.

Answer (score 2):

If $T^n = 0$ then the characteristic polynomial of $T$ is $x^i$ for some $i \leq n$. This means that the only eigenvalue of $T$ is $0$. $T-I$ is bijective as $1$ is not an eigenvalue, hence $-(T-I) = I-T$ is bijective.

Answer (score 1):

Since $T^n=0$ we have $I-T^n=I$, so if we factor that expression we get:
$$I=I-T^n=(I+T+T^2+...+T^{n-1})(I-T)$$
So we see that $I-T$ has an inverse because if we multiply $I-T$ by $I+T+T^2+...+T^{n-1}$ we obtain the identity operator. Since $I-T$ is invertible it is bijective.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $(I-T)x = 0$, then $x=Tx$ so that $x$ is a fixed point. Since $T$ is nilpotent this requires $x=0$ hence $I-T$ is injective.

For any $y$ define $y'=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} T^ky$. Then $Ty' = y'-y$ which may be written $y=(I-T)y'$, showing $I-T$ is surjective.